# Sorting by nested objects attributes in mongoose when using populate

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, aggregate-functions, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to sort parent documents by an attribute from a populated child document.

so if a person schema has an attribute business and the business schema has an attribute name, I want to sort the list of person documents by the name of their business alphabetically.

This seems very possible since the relationship between the person and business is always 1 to 1. but it seems mongoose doesn't allow such sorting mechanism as whenever I pass `business.name` as sorting arguments it will default sort instead (same sorting as passing unknown arguments).

I'm trying to use aggregate but the docs on that are very bad and not all arguments are clear.
I would like to know if there is a way of doing.

This is my aggregate code:

```
let populatedArray = [
            {
                "path": "business",
                "schema": require("../models/business").collection.name
            },
            {
                "path": "createdBy",
                "schema": require("../models/User").collection.name
            },
            {
                "path": "schema2",
                "schema": require("../models/schema2").collection.name
            },
            {
                "path": "schema3",
                "schema": require("../models/schema3").collection.name
            },
            {
                "path": "schema4",
                "schema": require("../models/schema4").collection.name
            },
            {
                "path": "schema5",
                "schema": require("../models/schema5").collection.name
            },
            {
                "path": "schema6",
                "schema": require("../models/schema6").collection.name,
                "populate": [{
                    "path": "schema7",
                    "schema": require("../models/schema7").collection.name
                }]
            }];

populatedArray.forEach((elem)=>{
            docsPromise.lookup({from:elem.schema,localField: elem.path, foreignField: '_id', as: elem.path})
            docsPromise.unwind("$"+elem.path)
        })
```

With the `unwind` command I get no documents. without the `unwind` command I get 500 documents while I only have 140 in the database. I know that aggregate is near a LEFT_JOIN on a SQL DB which can give similar result but I don't know to stop it form doing so.

Comment: If business having single element in array, then the sort operation `docsPromise.sort({ "business.name": 1 })` should work perfectly. second if you are not getting any document then there should be some issue in `localField` and `foreignField`, is local field object type id or string type, make sure to convert it using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`

Comment: i am pretty sure that the local field is a mongoose ObjectId reference. foreignField is the _id that is referenced by the localfield(`business`), which is the business `_id` field in this case

Comment: can you add more details, with more code or full query, this is not enough to see your problem.